# Removing back Slash from JSON in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting a JSON object from a webservice which after JSON.stringify().I am getting this output-`

```
[
    {
        "user": "A220",
        "shorttext": "shanghai",
        "reportedBy": "S,A",
        "questions": "[{\"question\":\"Q1\",\"is_mand\":\"0\",\"type\":\"text\",\"answer\":\"w\",\"ansYesOrNo\":false,\"ansDetails\":\"\"},{\"question\":\"Q2\",\"is_mand\":\"0\",\"type\":\"text\",\"answer\":\"ed\",\"ansYesOrNo\":false,\"ansDetails\":\"\"}]",
        "notifno": "20143995",
        "error": "",
        "createdOn": "2015-09-09 13:08:36",
        "Id": 0,
        "$$hashKey": "object:89"
    }
]
```

`

I want to remove all these back slash.
I tried using

```
var a=JSON.stringify(<that object>).replace(/\\/g, "");
```

But its giving result as a form string that too INVALID like this-

```
[
{
    "user": "A220",
    "shorttext": "shanghai",
    "reportedBy": "S,A",
    "questions": "[{"question":"Q1","is_mand":"0","type":"text","answer":"w","ansYesOrNo":false,"ansDetails":""},{"question":"Q2","is_mand":"0","type":"text","answer":"ed","ansYesOrNo":false,"ansDetails":""}]",
    "notifno": "20143995",
    "error": "",
    "createdOn": "2015-09-09 13:08:36",
    "Id": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:89"
}
```

]

My only objective is to remove the back slash without changing the data type.
I want to access the first question of questions.
Its not working...
JsFiddle link-[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/w02ck9uw/)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do JSON.stringify() in web service response. You can directly work like

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
then(function(response) 
{
   $scope.data = response;
}, 
function(response) 
{
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Now you have print in html like `{{data}}`

Comment: i am trying to access the first question of questions.I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to remove backslash from a JSON string

```
var data = {"\\id\\":"\\23232\\","\\pass\\":"\\1434\\"};
console.log(data);
var b=JSON.stringify(data);
str = b.replace(/\\/g, '');
console.log(str);
```